# how to export data from map function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm new to react and i'm trying to write a shopping cart with it, i need use the data of items that user selected from store to post it to the server this is my code so far:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';


class Food extends Component{


    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
        items:[],
    cart:[]
      };
    this.addToCart=this.addToCart.bind(this);

    }
componentWillReceiveProps(){
    if (this.props.product.length > 0){
        var info = this.props.product;
        this.setState({items: info});
    }
 }

   addToCart(item){
        var found = false;
        var updatedCart = this.state.cart.map((cartItem)=>{

            if(cartItem.Name === item.Name){
                found = true;
                cartItem.quantity++;
                return cartItem;
            } else{
                return cartItem;

            }
            });
            if (!found) {
                updatedCart.push({Id: item.ProductID, Name: item.Name, Price: item.Price, quantity: 1}) 
               }
               this.setState({
                cart: updatedCart
              });
        }



    render(){




           var products = this.state.items.map((item) => {

            return <Product details={item} addToCart={this.addToCart} key={item.ProductID} />
          })

            return (

                <div>
                  <nav>
                  <div><h3>{this.props.cat}</h3></div>
                    <Cart cart={this.state.cart}/>
                  </nav>
                    <div className="Products">  
                    {products}
                    </div>
                </div>
              );

    }
}



class Cart extends Component{
    constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
    open : false,
    total:0,
    quantity: 0
      };
      this.openCart = this.openCart.bind(this);
      this.postOrder = this.postOrder.bind(this);
    }

    openCart(){
        this.setState({open : !this.state.open});
    }

 postOrder(){
     alert('hello')
 }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
 <div className={"Cart " + (this.state.open ? "Cart-Open" : "")} onClick={this.openCart}>
        <p className="Title">Cart</p>
        <div>
        {this.props.cart.length > 0 ? this.props.cart.map((item) => {

            var itemSelected = [{'id': item.Id, 'quantity':item.quantity}]

            console.log("result",itemSelected);
            console.log("total",item.quantity*item.Price);

          return <p key={item.Id}>{item.Name}{item.quantity > 1 ? <span> {item.quantity}</span> : ''}</p> }) : <p>Empty</p>}
        </div>
        total : {this.state.total}

      </div>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.postOrder}>
       خرید  
      </Button>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

class Product extends Component{
constructor(props){
 super(props);
 this.state = {

  };
  this.addToCart = this.addToCart.bind(this);
}

addToCart(){
this.props.addToCart (this.props.details);
}
render(){

    let item = this.props.details;

    return(
         <div className="Product" onClick={this.addToCart}>
        <Grid container spacing={24}> 
<Grid item xs={6} key={item.ProductID}>
<Paper className="food-item">
        <p>{item.Name}</p>
        <p>{item.Excerpt}</p>
        <p>{item.Price}</p>
        </Paper> 
</Grid> 
</Grid> 
      </div>

    )
}

}

export default Food;
```

as you see in cart component i get the data that user selected and store it to 'itemSelected' variable now i want setState that but i don't know how can i export the data from map function scope, also i can't setState it inside the render method (because this cause infinite loop).
how can i setState my data?

thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Can you tell more about your obstacle? Detailed error trace would help.

Comment: Making all your changes inside `ComponentWillReceiveProps` will be the best approach.

Comment: The method `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated. I wouldn't advise using it. Use `componentDidUpdate` instead.

Comment: for more details i would say i have a map function inside the render method (you can see it in Cart component) i have to use that map function to iterate the array that received from  Food component, now i want use this iterated data inside the postOrder method, notice that i can't setState this data inside the render method so my only way is setState outside that. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Inside your postOrder(), you need to iterate cart items like the below code sample. And, you do not need to keep the data in state.

```
postOrder() {
 const itemsSelected = this.props.cart.map((item) => {
    return {
       'id': item.Id,
       'quantity':item.quantity 
    };
 }
 console.log(itemsSelected);
 // now, you can post your selected cart items to server here...
 alert('hello')
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work because, if you notice on my code, the data will be processed inside the render method, i need that processed data, but thank you very much

Comment: anyways, you should not process the data in render(), instead, you should define another function which does the processing logic viz processCartItems(), and then you should call processCartItems() inside render() and postOrder().

Answer (score 0):

```js
getCartData() {
    const cartData = this.state.cart.map(function (cartItem) {
      return {
        'id': cartItem.id,
        'name': cartItem.name
      };
    })
    console.log('cartData',cartData)
    this.setState({ cart: cartData })
  }
```

Comment: this also doesn't work for the same reason and also apparently when we define a map function scope we can export data from it so 'cartDate' outside this scope in undefined for react, but thanks for your help